# Ruby access propteries with dot-notation

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a class that will basically be used as a data structure for storing values/nested values. I want there to be two methods, `get` and `set`, that accept a dot-notated path to recursively set or get variables.

For example:

```
bag = ParamBag.new
bag.get('foo.bar') # => nil
bag.set('foo.bar', 'baz')
bag.get('foo.bar') # => 'baz'
```

The `get` method could also take a default return value if the value doesn't exist:

```
bag.get('foo.baz', false) # => false
```

I could also initialize a new `ParamBag` with a Hash.

How would I manage this in Ruby? I've done this in other languages, but in order to set a recursive path, I would take the value by reference, but I'm not sure how I'd do it in Ruby.

Comment: Take a look at Hashie or DeepOpenStruct...

Comment: What's wrong with Struct or OpenStruct?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `attr_reader`? It's a lot simpler than passing a property through a method.

Comment: The idea is that I want to be able to reference potentially nested variables that aren't there without getting 'undefined method'.

Comment: Asking if a gem exists immediately puts your question off-topic, because you're asking for recommendations for off-site references. Instead, tell us what you've done, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Alex you need to tag people or else we don't know if you've responded to us. _You_ get a notification for comments on _your_ posts. We don't. And what exactly do you mean by nested variables?

Comment: Sorry @c650. When I mean nested variables, I want to be able to say `foo = new ParamBag` and then have `foo.get('bar.baz')` to return nil. OpenStruct (or DeepOpenStruct) returns `undefined method of nil object` since neither foo nor foo.bar were set.

@theTinMan, I'd like to pass in a dot-delimited string and retrieve the values by that. If you take a look at the `get` and `set` methods here, that's basically what I'm trying to achieve. https://github.com/alex-phillips/Utilities/blob/master/src/Utility/Traits/Bag.php#L262

Answer (score 3):

This was a fun exercise but still falls under the "you probably should not do this" category.

To accomplish what you want, OpenStruct can be used with some slight modifications.

```
class ParamBag < OpenStruct
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if super.nil?
      modifiable[new_ostruct_member(name)] = ParamBag.new
    end    
  end
end
```

This class will let you chain however many method calls together you would like and set any number of parameters.

Tested with Ruby 2.2.1

```
2.2.1 :023 > p = ParamBag.new
 => #<ParamBag> 
2.2.1 :024 > p.foo
 => #<ParamBag> 
2.2.1 :025 > p.foo.bar
 => #<ParamBag> 
2.2.1 :026 > p.foo.bar = {}
 => {} 
2.2.1 :027 > p.foo.bar
 => {} 
2.2.1 :028 > p.foo.bar = 'abc'
 => "abc"
```

Basically, take your `get` and `set` methods away and call methods like you would normally.

I do not advise you actually do this, I would instead suggest you use `OpenStruct` by itself to acheive some flexibility without going too crazy. If you find yourself needing to chain a ton of methods and have them never fail, maybe take a step backwards and ask "is this really the right way to approach this problem?".  If the answer to that question is a resounding yes, then `ParamBag` might just be perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Really, I'm working with an API which returns JSON objects (sometimes some properties exist, others they don't if the property isn't there). So rather than individual getter methods for everything, it'd be nice to load in a hash and just reference by dot-notated keys instead of checking if each part of the 'path' is actually set or not.

Comment: I'd need more information about the data you're working with and how you really intend to use it but it sounds like what you want is to turn a JSON object into a ruby hash and then that ruby hash into an object. For that, I'm not sure there is enough magic to help you, you might have to do some things manually.

Comment: If you take a look at the `get` and `set` methods in this PHP trait, that's basically what I'm trying to achieve, @yez. But pass-by-reference doesn't seem to exist in Ruby.